# How to extract a UTF-8 string (In Arabic) from a MySQL DB and echo to screen using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I have a MySQL db, i've set collation = utf8_unicode_ci.

I'm trying to fetch the value through PHP but i'm getting "???" instead of the actual string.

I have read about this subject and tried using mb_convert_encoding but it didn't work, what am I missing?

Can someone please post a code snippet that actually pulls a value from a DB and echos the string to the screen?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> I have a MySQL db, i've set collation = utf8_unicode_ci.
>
> I'm trying to fetch the value through PHP but i'm getting "???" instead of the actual string.

Character sets are how characters are *encoded*.

Collations are how characters are *sorted*.

These are different things.  Chances are that your tables or columns have the right collation, but the wrong character set.  [The Internationalization section of the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internationalization-localization.html) has a great deal of information on how to set things up correctly.

> Can someone please post a code snippet that actually pulls a value from a DB and echos the string to the screen?

Let's demonstrate how to use utf8 as a character set, and the utf8 "general case insensitive" collation.  I'm using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in this example, but the same general idea should work with `mysqli` as well.  I wouldn't advise using the old `mysql` extension.

```
// Let's tell MySQL we're going to be working with utf8 data.
// http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// Create a table with our proper charset and collation.
// If we needed to, we could specify the charset and collation with
// each column. 
// http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-column.html
// We could also set the defaults at the database level.
// http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-database.html
$db->query('
    CREATE TABLE foo(
        bar TEXT
    ) 
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci
    ENGINE=InnoDB
');

// I don't know Arabic, so I'll type this in English.  It should
// work fine in Arabic, as long as the string is encoded as utf8.    
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES(?)");
$sth->execute(array("Hello, world!"));

$sth = $db->query("SELECT bar FROM foo LIMIT 1");
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $row[0]; // Will echo "Hello, world!", or whatever you inserted.
```

---

@tomp's comment below is correct.  Make sure to emit a proper character set with your content type header.  For example:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // Note the dash!
```

Comment: Also the output device should expect output in Unicode, so if you are using HTML, you should add meta tag specifying the UTF-8 encoding for the browser to know how to render it.